# Is the General Cirrate Octopus Form the Basalmost Octopoda Morphology?

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, cephalopods

The reason I ask this is due to the distinctive internal mantle shells of cirrina, of which the incerrata have stylets that are a remnant of the cirrate shell. Along with this, both cirrate octopuses and Vampyroteuthis have a gladius (although with different morphologies) with fins upon their mantles, which incirrate octopuses lack.

Also, a [relatively recent study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5813590/) presents a view that cirrate octopuses are actually paraphyletic, being an evolutionary grade rather than a monophyletic group. Can it be inferred then that the basalmost octopus form is then a pelagic form with a gladius that uses mantle fins as the primary form of locomotion, and the incirrate form normally associated with octopuses is a drastic deviation?